# dataframe, set index from list

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible when creating a dataframe from a list, to set the index as one of the values?

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = [['a', 'a1'], ['b',' b1']]

df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["First", "Second"])

        First  Second
0          a   a1
1          b   b1
```

And how I'd like it to look:

```
        First  Second
a          a   a1
b          b   b1
```

Comment: `df.index = df.First`

Comment: Note: as others have mentioned, if you would like to make an existing column as index **opt-1**: `df.set_index('col_name', inplace=True)`, if you would like to use an external object like list, pd.Series as your index instead **opt-2**: `df.index = list_1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["First", "Second"]).set_index('First', drop=False)
      First Second
First             
a         a     a1
b         b     b1
```

Comment: If I want to set another list as index (let say ['x','y']) which is not the existing column of the data frame then how can I do it?

Answer (score 25):

Change it to list before assigning it to index

```
df.index = list(df["First"])
```

Comment: This option is versatile, enables creating index from external objects (lists, pd.Series etc), and also answers OP's question too.

Answer (score 13):

### [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html)

To set *arbitrary values* as the index, best practice is to use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_axis(['idx1', 'idx2'])

#       First  Second
# idx1      a      a1
# idx2      b      b1
```

---

### [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) (list vs array)

It's also possible to pass arbitrary values to [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), but note the difference between passing a list vs array:

- **list** — [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) assigns these *columns* as the index:

  ```
  df.set_index(['First', 'First'])

  #              Second
  # First First        
  # a     a          a1
  # b     b          b1
  ```
- **array** (Series/Index/ndarray) — [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) assigns these *values* as the index:

  ```
  df = df.set_index(pd.Series(['First', 'First']))

  #        First  Second
  # First      a      a1
  # First      b      b1
  ```

  <sub>*Note that passing arrays to [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is [very contentious among the devs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24046) and [may even get deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24046#issuecomment-451827403).*</sub>

---

### Why not just modify `df.index` directly?

Directly modifying attributes is fine and is used often, but using methods has its advantages:

- Methods provide better error checking, e.g.:

  ```
  df = df.set_axis(['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3'])

  # ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements
  ```

  ```
  df.index = ['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3']

  # No error despite length mismatch
  ```
- Methods can be chained, e.g.:

  ```
  df.some_method().set_axis(['idx1', 'idx2']).another_method()
  ```

Comment: set_axis() is also the way to go to make mypy happy! df.index = [...] makes mypy unhappy because df.index is not of type list.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want index name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["First", "Second"], index=[i[0] for i in tmp])
```

Result:

```
  First Second
a     a     a1
b     b     b1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = [['a', 'a1'], ['b',' b1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["First", "Second"]).set_axis([tmp[0][0],tmp[1][0]])
df
```