# How do I name the column and index in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add names to my columns and indices of a pandas dataframe.

Right now,

```
Int64Index([2, 4, 5, 32, 112, 344, 543],
          dtype='int64')
```

is my list of column names. I want to make this such that we have

```
Int64Index([2, 4, 5, 32, 112, 344, 543],
          dtype='int64', name='mid')
```

instead, so the 'mid' shows up as a label for the top column.

How do I do this? I tried setting

```
df.columns=
Int64Index([2, 4, 5, 32, 112, 344, 543],
          dtype='int64', name='mid')
```

but I got an error that Int64Index is not defined. I don't understand this. How do I just simply add a name to my index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-columns-in-pandas) & [dataframe, set index from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132181/dataframe-set-index-from-list)

Comment: `df.index.name = 'your_name'`, or `df.columns.name = ...`